# Execute SQL files from SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a lot of *.sql script files and i want to incorporate them to my SSIS package.

Is it possible to use these *.sql files as the source of Select/Insert/Update/Create/Alter/Drop statements on my package?

The goal is to dynamically alter the scripts without modifying the package.

Thanks

Comment: You can also use sqlcmd `:r`https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1543/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-multiple-sql-server-scripts/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Execute SQL Task where the statements come from these sql files. For example if you loop all your files of *.sql type in a foreach loop, then use Execute SQL task on the file connection you're looping on, you should be able to run all these SQL files without any problems. (Change SQLSourceType in the General pane of the Execute SQL Task editor)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, though I need more test if this will be workable for T-SQL & Cursor. [Passing in the SQL Statement from a File](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx)

Comment: Last question, How do you loop files using Foreach Loop ?

Comment: [Looping over files with the Foreach Loop](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx) & [SSIS: Dynamically specify folder path for Foreach File Enumerator in Foreach Loop Container](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changliw/archive/2010/07/19/ssis-dynamically-specify-folder-path-for-foreach-file-enumerator-in-foreach-loop-editor-task.aspx)

Comment: ForEach puts the filePath in variable. Unfortunately, ExecuteSQLTask needs SQL not the filePath. Any idea how to actually read the file and put it in a variable for ExecuteSQLTask. If we use FileConnectionManager for ExecuteSQLTask, then it just executes that single sql file.

Comment: @coding_idiot, The last sentence is the key. Change the SqlSourceType to FileConnection and it will ask for a file, not direct SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using .sql files, you can set SQL Statements to come from Variables.  You can set these variables from Package Configurations, which can be in the form of XML files.  These XML files can store the SQL, and you can alter them without having to edit or redeploy your packages, which should give you the flexibility you're looking for.  [This](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_2005_making_ssis_packages_portable.htm) link tells you how to set this up.

Comment: Ok I will check, But what if i have to execute thousands of lines of statement, because I have a file that has 10,000 lines of insert into statements ?

Comment: Yeah that's not really going to be workable.  You'd be better creating something like a load or staging database to insert that data into a table, and then load in the main package from there.