# SQL Server .sql files containing test cases

Tags: sql-server, testing, ssis, etl, software-quality

We have a large set of test cases (hundreds) stored in `.sql` files that validate data deliverables from ETL processes. We would like to automate the execution of these. If not automate, run them in batch via a scheduler. They need to be done outside of the ETL package as they are owned by SQA not Devs.

What is the best approach to getting this done?

We would likely log the results to a DB table as well but haven't ironed that out yet. Welcome any tips/suggestions on either topic.

Comment: Give those a read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549393/execute-sql-files-from-ssis-package

Comment: From a logging perspective, I think we will just direct the result to a flat file using sqlcmd mode and ':out xxxxxx'.  Still struggling with getting executing a batch of .sql files though.  Sorta like the idea of powershell but am not sure I can get the required permissions in place to script this.

Answer (score 0):

1. foreach loop to get file names to a variable (let's call it vFileName)
2. script task to read sql file to a variable (Read - vFileName Read/Write vSQL)

   ```
   Dts.Variables["vSQL"].Value = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Dts.Variables["vFileName"].Value.ToString());
   ```
3. Execute SQL Task and execute the variable vSQL.

Please bear with me as I typed this in here. I might be a little off with how you reference variables in a script task.

Logging is either another exec SQL or an addition to the vSQL variable

Comment: Thanks Keith.  Our testers write .sql files in SSMS.  I am trying to find a solution that lets us write .sql flies and just batch execute them, maybe in powershell.  SSIS work opens up a new set of requirements for the team I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use Invoke-Sqlcmd. This is a potential example:

```
    #Provide SQLServerName
    $SQLServer ="MySQLSErver\InstanceName"
    #Provide Database Name 
    $DatabaseName ="Test"
    #Scripts Folder Path
    $FolderPath ="C:\MyScripts\Test\"

    #Loop through the .sql files and run them
    foreach ($filename in get-childitem -path $FolderPath -filter "*.sql")
    {
    invoke-sqlcmd –ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -InputFile 
    $filename.fullname
    }
```

[Here](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-powershells-invoke-sqlcmd/) is a good writeup about the process